# entity relationships logic in business layer or in persistence layer(repository)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, design-patterns

I am confused about where I should implement logic, which describes entities relationships.
For example, I have 2 entites: User and Role with Many to Many relationship.

User repository code looks like:

```
 public override void Insert(User user)
        {
            foreach (Group group in user.Groups)
            {
                List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();

                foreach(decimal id in user.Groups.Select(g => g.Id))
                {
                    Group g = _context.Groups.Find(id);
                    groups.Add(g);
                }

                user.Groups = groups;
            }

            _context.Users.Insert(user);
        }
```

may be repository shuoldn't take care about relations?

or it should be in business service:

```
private GroupRepository _groupRepository;
private UserRepository _userRepositpry;

public override void Insert(User user)
{
    foreach (Group group in user.Groups)
    {  
       // ...

       foreach(decimal id in user.Groups.Select(g => g.Id))
       {
          Group g = _groupRepository.Get(id)
          user.Add(g);
        }
     }

     _userRepository.Insert(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your first approach using the repository pattern is best as I think the repository pattern fits nicely with MVC. So I think the first method is best, using the repository pattern (using either an MVC/MVVM pattern for web or an MVP pattern for winforms).

I like to keep the repository as a data access layer that can either do direct database calls, or it can be hooked up into the entity framework.

With the repository pattern and the code above, best to have the more methods in the repository in case it was to be reused in future - e.g. one for getting the groups, one for inserting etc and then these individual repository methods are then called in the controller.

Example code below use to indicate pattern only:

Controller class GroupController.cs

```
private GroupRepository groupRepository = new GroupRepository();
private UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();

// entry point to controller class
public ActionResult Group()
{ 
    // Make call to repository to get group
    Group group = GetGroupsForUser(user);

    // Make call to repository to insert user
    InsertUser();
}

private Group GetGroupsForUser(User user)
{
    List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();

    // Call to get user details - for demo purposes
    foreach (IdentityReference domainGroup in WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups)
    {
       IdentityReference group = domainGroup.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
       groups.Add(group);
    }
}

private void InsertUser()
{
    bool success = groupRepository.PopulateGroup(user)
}
```

The repository should be used mainly as a data access layer for database/entity framework calls and the controller should be influencing what data gets populated into the models.